# WSO2 Converts embedded XML to JSON in Payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I embed an XML into a JSON for the field `details` and wso2 converts it to JSON. How can I resolve this?

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>{
    "Customer": {
        "name": "$1",
        "details": "$2"
       }
  }</format>
  <args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('name')"/>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('detail')"/>
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Output

```
{
    "Customer": {
        "name": "Adam",
        "details": "{"id": "123"}"
    }
}
```

expected

```
{
    "Customer": {
        "name": "Adam",
        "details": "<id>123</id>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the flag `literal="true"` in the PLFactory args.

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>{
    "Customer": {
        "name": "$1",
        "details": "$2"
       }
  }</format>
  <args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('name')"/>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('detail') literal="true" />
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```